# i have an if statement with same code inside

Tags: java

so.. i have a java code like this

```
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String sebelumnrp = text1.getText().toString();
            int nrp = Integer.parseInt(sebelumnrp);
            String idb = text11.getText().toString();
            int id = Integer.parseInt(idb);
            String sebelumjob = text2.getText().toString();
            int codejob = Integer.parseInt(sebelumjob);
            if (nrp == 80110005){
                SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                String nama = "AKHMAD ROZA′I";
                if(codejob == 100) {
                    db.execSQL("insert into jan(no, instructor, branch, area, codejob, category, codecategory, activity, description, sapsomp, periodestart, periodeend, hrs, venue, vendor, unittype, remark, nomor) values('" + nrp + "','" + nama +"' ,'BLP',' TTA BALIKPAPAN','" + codejob + "', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Cuti(Tahunan, Site)', '" + text3.getText().toString() + "', '" + text4.getText().toString() + "', '" + text5.getText().toString() + "', '" + text6.getText().toString() + "', '" + text7.getText().toString() + "', '" + text8.getText().toString() + "', '" + text9.getText().toString() + "', '" + text10.getText().toString() + "','" + id + "')");
                    codejob();
                }
                if(codejob == 101) {
                    db.execSQL("insert into jan(no, instructor, branch, area, codejob, category, codecategory, activity, description, sapsomp, periodestart, periodeend, hrs, venue, vendor, unittype, remark, nomor) values('" + nrp + "','" + nama + "' ,'BLP',' TTA BALIKPAPAN','" + codejob + "', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Ijin', '" + text3.getText().toString() + "', '" + text4.getText().toString() + "', '" + text5.getText().toString() + "', '" + text6.getText().toString() + "', '" + text7.getText().toString() + "', '" + text8.getText().toString() + "', '" + text9.getText().toString() + "', '" + text10.getText().toString() + "','" + id + "')");
                    codejob();
                }
                if(codejob == 102) {
                    db.execSQL("insert into jan(no, instructor, branch, area, codejob, category, codecategory, activity, description, sapsomp, periodestart, periodeend, hrs, venue, vendor, unittype, remark, nomor) values('" + nrp + "','" + nama + "' ,'BLP',' TTA BALIKPAPAN','" + codejob + "', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Sakit', '" + text3.getText().toString() + "', '" + text4.getText().toString() + "', '" + text5.getText().toString() + "', '" + text6.getText().toString() + "', '" + text7.getText().toString() + "', '" + text8.getText().toString() + "', '" + text9.getText().toString() + "', '" + text10.getText().toString() + "','" + id + "')");
                    codejob();
                }
                if(codejob == 103) {
                    db.execSQL("insert into jan(no, instructor, branch, area, codejob, category, codecategory, activity, description, sapsomp, periodestart, periodeend, hrs, venue, vendor, unittype, remark, nomor) values('" + nrp + "','" + nama + "' ,'BLP',' TTA BALIKPAPAN','" + codejob + "', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Alpha', '" + text3.getText().toString() + "', '" + text4.getText().toString() + "', '" + text5.getText().toString() + "', '" + text6.getText().toString() + "', '" + text7.getText().toString() + "', '" + text8.getText().toString() + "', '" + text9.getText().toString() + "', '" + text10.getText().toString() + "','" + id + "')");
                    codejob();
                    } else {
                    jika();
                }
            /* Batas */

            }                
            if (nrp == 80111315) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            String nama = "INDRA YULIATMA";
                if(codejob == 100) {
                    db.execSQL("insert into jan(no, instructor, branch, area, codejob, category, codecategory, activity, description, sapsomp, periodestart, periodeend, hrs, venue, vendor, unittype, remark, nomor) values('" + nrp + "','" + nama + "' ,'BLP',' TTA BALIKPAPAN','" + codejob + "', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Cuti(Tahunan, Site)', '" + text3.getText().toString() + "', '" + text4.getText().toString() + "', '" + text5.getText().toString() + "', '" + text6.getText().toString() + "', '" + text7.getText().toString() + "', '" + text8.getText().toString() + "', '" + text9.getText().toString() + "', '" + text10.getText().toString() + "','" + id + "')");
                    codejob();
                }
                if(codejob == 101) {
                    db.execSQL("insert into jan(no, instructor, branch, area, codejob, category, codecategory, activity, description, sapsomp, periodestart, periodeend, hrs, venue, vendor, unittype, remark, nomor) values('" + nrp + "','" + nama + "' ,'BLP',' TTA BALIKPAPAN','" + codejob + "', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Ijin', '" + text3.getText().toString() + "', '" + text4.getText().toString() + "', '" + text5.getText().toString() + "', '" + text6.getText().toString() + "', '" + text7.getText().toString() + "', '" + text8.getText().toString() + "', '" + text9.getText().toString() + "', '" + text10.getText().toString() + "','" + id + "')");
                    codejob();
                }
                if(codejob == 102) {

                    db.execSQL("insert into jan(no, instructor, branch, area, codejob, category, codecategory, activity, description, sapsomp, periodestart, periodeend, hrs, venue, vendor, unittype, remark, nomor) values('" + nrp + "','" + nama + "' ,'BLP',' TTA BALIKPAPAN','" + codejob + "', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Sakit', '" + text3.getText().toString() + "', '" + text4.getText().toString() + "', '" + text5.getText().toString() + "', '" + text6.getText().toString() + "', '" + text7.getText().toString() + "', '" + text8.getText().toString() + "', '" + text9.getText().toString() + "', '" + text10.getText().toString() + "','" + id + "')");
                    codejob();
                }
                if(codejob == 103) {

                    db.execSQL("insert into jan(no, instructor, branch, area, codejob, category, codecategory, activity, description, sapsomp, periodestart, periodeend, hrs, venue, vendor, unittype, remark, nomor) values('" + nrp + "','" + nama + "' ,'BLP',' TTA BALIKPAPAN','" + codejob + "', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Alpha', '" + text3.getText().toString() + "', '" + text4.getText().toString() + "', '" + text5.getText().toString() + "', '" + text6.getText().toString() + "', '" + text7.getText().toString() + "', '" + text8.getText().toString() + "', '" + text9.getText().toString() + "', '" + text10.getText().toString() + "','" + id + "')");
                    codejob();
                } else {
                jika();
            }
        /* Batas */

        }
```

and i want to make it more simply.. can u guys help me to simplify it?

i have much trouble when i try to make it.. cause like it always showing me a problem with the "nama" variable inside db.execsql

Comment: [Using prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) will help reduce the clutter at the very least

Comment: Have a look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com (read their help center); if your code currently works, then your question may be on topic there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the insert statements are all the same except for one string in the middle. I would start by making a single string for the larger part that is the same, and put in a parameter for the part that's different:

```
String sqlStatementFormat = "insert into jan(no, instructor, branch, area, codejob, category, codecategory, activity, description, sapsomp, periodestart, periodeend, hrs, venue, vendor, unittype, remark, nomor) values('" + nrp + "','" + nama + "' ,'BLP',' TTA BALIKPAPAN','" + codejob + "', 'Absent', 'Absent', 'Absent', '%s', '" + text3.getText().toString() + "', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')"
```

Then I would use a HashMap to store the different "codeJob" strings for each integer:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(100, "Cuti(Tahunan, Site)");
map.put(101, "etc");
```

and so forth.

Then, instead of an `if` statement to get the right text, you do something like:

```
String codeString = map.get(codeJob);
String sql = String.format(sqlFormat, codeString, text3.getText().toString(), text4.getText().toString, text5.getText().toString(), text6.getText().toString(), text7.getText().toString(), text8.getText().toString(), text9.getText().toString(), text10.getText().toString(), id);
```

You can do a similar thing with the "nrp" integer; there's no reason you can't have another map with indices of legal values for that. But this would make it much simpler, and will give you the idea.

Comment: how to execute the sqlite when i do something like that?

Comment: With `db.execSql(sql)`, assuming the string variable name is `sql` as it is in the suggestion I gave. The `db.execSql()` call takes a string as an argument, my suggestion builds that string with a base and parameters instead of using a string literal (i.e., a hard-coded string with double quotes around it).

Comment: You mention "trouble with the 'nama' variable" in your original post -- I have no idea what that problem is, you would have to copy that error message and post it here for us to do so.

Comment: It is customary to mark an answer as "correct" if it solves your problem, and to upvote it if it's helpful at all - I mention it since you seem new to the site.

Comment: sounds like you need another question - 2 String? In the middle of what? Different value from what? I don't know what you're asking

Comment: I'll take a stab at your meaning, though I don't know why: "What if there are two strings that depend on codeJob that have to be inserted into two places in the resulting SQL statement?" In that case, you could have a map declared as `HashMap<String, String[]>`, and store the two strings in the array that you get as a value from the map's `get` function. If the two strings don't both depend on the same thing, then perhaps you need two different maps.

Comment: umm sorry my bad.. i dont speak english pretty well

Comment: I apologize if I was not sensitive enough to that. I admire anyone who can conduct business at all in a second language, especially since I cannot. If you want to attempt another question, or tell me what is different between your situation and the question I guessed at in the comment above, I'll try again.